# Does a uniformly sequence of harmonic function converge to a harmonic function?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of harmonic function and $f_n$ uniformly converge to a function $f$. Prove that the function $f$ is harmonic.

Is this statement true?

Comment: Yes. Hint: Mean value property.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because the limit is a continuous function that satisfies the mean value property, and any such function is harmonic. The mean value property passes to the limit because uniform convergence guarantees the convergence of integrals over spheres. (As timur wrote.)

In fact, it suffices  to assume that the convergence is uniform on every compact subset of the domain. This assumption is easier to verify and holds more often in practice.